# ImageView will not resize properly

Tags: java, android, uiimageview, imageview, android-viewpager

I'm attempting to get an imageview (classical_up_btn) to fill the width of the screen correctly however it appears to be cut off by the next image it is supposed to load when swiped

Any suggestions as to how this can be resolved?

Thanks!

### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

### JAVA:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] { R.drawable.classical_up_btn,
                R.drawable.country_up_btn, R.drawable.dance_up_btn,
                R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn };

        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = Home.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
                    R.dimen.padding_medium);
            imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);

should be:

imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);